# Angular consoled data showing null

Tags: angular

I am very confused with a problem that I am experiencing. I am trying to send a model to a post request. However when I console.log the model out in my browser, I see the following.

[image]

If I then expand the consoled result by clicking on the arrow I see this

[image: r]

My request is failing because it is seeing the null value but there is actually data. Please assist.

My request looks like this

```
const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
const headers = new HttpHeaders()
  .set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`)
  .set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
const options = { headers: headers };
console.log(this.model);
this.http.post('https://localhost:44345/api/Corporates/Create', this.model, options)
.subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
})
```

Model

```
  protected initModel() {
    this.model = {
      basics: null,
      retirements: null,
      risk: null,
      users: null
    };
  }
```

Populate model

```
  saveTemp( args: { tabName: string, tabModel: any } ) {
    switch (args.tabName) {
      case 'basics': {
        this.model.basics = args.tabModel;
        // console.log(this.model.basics);
        break;
      }
      case 'retirement': {
        this.model.retirements = args.tabModel;
        break;
      }
      case 'risk': {
        this.model.risk = args.tabModel;
        break;
      }
      case 'users': {
        this.model.users = args.tabModel;
        break;
      }
      default: {
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing your request creation and how you are making the service call along with how is it sent in payload?

Comment: updated question

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are passing default null value to model

and in saveTemp()
you assigning value to your local variable but not assigning that variable to model.

can you try something like this;

```
protected initModel() {
    this.model = {
      basics: this.model.basics
      retirements: this.model.retirements
      risk:  this.model.risk
      users: this.model.users
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's very possible that when you `console.log(this.model);`, the model object is at its default (all null), so you see all null values without expanding the object in your console. You post your model data to the API right after this, and your server is receiving null values. (If you put a breakpoint at `this.http.post`, and go expand your object in console, you will see all null too. )

I would assume your `saveTemp` function's 'basics' case was triggered after you call the API, so you see values in the console after expanding the object (If the object content being updated after it's printed in console, you would be able to see the updates by expanding it).

Make sure you call the API AFTER this.model being updated.